# How to handle GuzzleHttp errors

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I have data fetching from API and I want to handle errors for that API data because currently if for any reason that data couldn't be fetch my page stops loading and shows error, what I want is if getting api results failed for any reason just set value as null, therefore the rest of page can be loaded just this API data will not.

```
public function index() {
    $myData = ....;
    $minutes = 60;
    $forecast = Cache::remember('forecast', $minutes, function () {
        $app_id = env('HERE_APP_ID');
        $app_code = env('HERE_APP_CODE');
        $lat = env('HERE_LAT_DEFAULT');
        $lng = env('HERE_LNG_DEFAULT');
        $url = "https://weather.ls.hereapi.com/weather/1.0/report.json?product=forecast_hourly&name=Chicago&apiKey=$app_code&language=en-US";
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $res = $client->get($url);
        if ($res->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            $j = $res->getBody();
            $obj = json_decode($j);
            $forecast = $obj->hourlyForecasts->forecastLocation;
        }
        return $forecast;
    });
    return view('panel.index', compact('myData', 'forecast'));
}
```

I want if forecast failed to fetch, data of `$forecast` be set to  `null`

**any idea?**

Comment: there are a lot of answers regarding handling guzzle exception in stackoverflow as well as docs, you should search more for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per in the : [Docs](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#exceptions)

You can handle the exception

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException - 400 errors
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException - 500 errors
```

or you can use the super class of it

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException
```

You can use try catch

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

try {

    $res = $client->get($url);

    if ($res->getStatusCode() == 200) {
        $j = $res->getBody();
        $obj = json_decode($j);
        $forecast = $obj->hourlyForecasts->forecastLocation;
    }

} catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
    // handle the response exception
    $forecast = null;
}
```